# Invalid Datatype for user defined table type

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have declared the following user defined table type

```
CREATE TYPE [component].[programmeList] AS TABLE
(
    ProgrammeId [bigint] NOT NULL
)
GO
```

Now when i pass it as parameter to an SP

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [component].[Get_Live_Examination_Status]
    @AssessmentPeriodId INT,
    @ResponseFormatType INT,
    @ProgrammeList AS component.programmeList 
AS
BEGIN
```

I keep getting the following error

> Parameter or variable has invalid datatype

Comment: See [CREATE PROCEDURE (Transact-SQL): Using a Table-Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#g-using-a-table-valued-parameter) and you'll see your problem.

Comment: @Larnu It was some issue with SSMS.

Comment: No, it wasn't @techno , your syntax was wrong. Nothing was wrong with SSMS.

Comment: @Larnu I had used the correct syntax as mentioned in the answer below.Still the issue was there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass this argument as :

```
@ProgrammeList component.programmeList READONLY
```

Comment: Had declared like this before.On restarting SSMS it was fixed.